# Laravel 8 - CAN delete but CANNOT UPDATE parent row due to integrity constraints violation: foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a truck table, a package table, and a postman table. Truck table and package table has a one to many relationship. Truck table and postman table has a one to one relationship.

Now I can delete truck table just fine, but I got integrity constraints violation error inside the truck table when I try to **update** `postman_name` on truck data that has packages assigned to it. I don't get the error when I try to change other non-foreign key properties or when I try to change `postman_name` on a truck data that currently has zero package assigned.

I only got the error when I try to **update** `postman_name` on a `truck_number` with packages assigned to it.

How can I fix this error?

the postman form inside `truck/edit.blade.php` :

```php
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="postman_name">Postman in Charge</label>
                <select name="truck_number" class="form-control">
                <option selected disabled>-</option>
                @foreach ($postmen as $count => $postman)
                  <option value="{{$postman['postman_name']}}">{{$postman['postman_name']}}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
</div>
```

Truck update controller:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $truck_id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'truck_number'=>'required|unique:trucks,truck_id',
            'postman_name',
            'date_of_operation'=>'required'
        ]);
        $trucks = Truck::find($truck_id);
        $trucks->truck_number =  $request->get('truck_number');
        $trucks->postman_name = $request->get('postman_name');
        $trucks->date_of_operation = $request->get('date_of_operation');
        $trucks->save();
        return redirect(TRUCK)->with('success', 'Truck Updated!');
    }
```

Package migration file:

```php
Schema::create('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('package_id');
            $table->string('truck_number')->nullable(); 
            $table->foreign('truck_number')->references('truck_number')->on('trucks')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('package_number')->unique();
            $table->string('receiver_name');
            $table->string('destination');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

postman migration file:

```php
Schema::create('postmen', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('postman_id');
            $table->string('truck_number')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('truck_number')->references('truck_number')->on('trucks')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('postman_number')->unique();
            $table->string('postman_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

truck migration file:

```php
Schema::create('trucks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('truck_id');
            $table->string('truck_number')->unique();
            $table->string('postman_name')->nullable();
            $table->date('date_of_operation');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Models:

```
class postman extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'postman_id';

    protected $fillable = ['truck_number','postman_number','postman_name'];

    public function Truck(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Truck::class);
    }
}

class Package extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'package_id';

    protected $fillable = ['truck_number', 'package_number', 'receiver_name', 'destination'];
    
     public function Truck(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Truck::class);
    }

}

class Truck extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'truck_id';
    protected $fillable = ['truck_number', 'postman_name', 'date_of_operation', 'status'];
    
     public function Package()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Package::class, 'truck_number', 'truck_number');
    }

     public function postman()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(postman::class, 'truck_number', 'truck_number');
    }

}
```

note: by the way, I also cannot add `$table->foreign('postman_name')->references('postman_name')->on('postmen')->onDelete('cascade');` to truck migration file. it throws this error when I do that:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `proj_db`.`trucks` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: I think you need to add `->onUpdate('cascade')` too on migration

Comment: @sta may I know to which migration file should I add that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may work with onUpdate,  you can try `$table->foreign('truck_number')->references('truck_number')->on('trucks')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');`

Comment: Your foreign key cant be a string, you need to change too `$table->integer('truck_number')->nullable();`

Comment: @sta but i used the same `truck_number` string foreign key on my package table and i can do fine with updating and deleting stuffs? by the way, following ur advice, I don't get the error anymore after adding `onUpdate('cascade')` , but when i update `postman_name` on truck table, it doesn't show any data. it's just blank, it's like it doesn't read the update input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `postman_name` column to be unique on postmen table:

```
$table->string('postman_name')->unique();
```

And in your Truck model you need to specify the foreign key name and the local key name, like this:

```
return $this->hasOne(postman::class, 'postman_name','postman_name');
```

Change your relationship in postman Model

```
public function truck(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Track::class, 'postman_name', 'postman_name');
}
```

and in Truck model

```
public function postman(){
    return $this->hasOne(Postman::class, 'postman_name', 'postman_name');
}
```

Comment: I did that, now it no longer throws the error, but problem is, `postman_name` does not get updated. the value is displayed empty on my truck index page. I wonder if it's because I cannot specify postmen foreign key constraints on my truck migration file

Comment: it's still throwing error when I do that. I wonder if it has to do with truck migration being the first position on the migration list. But then I'm sure I'll get error no matter which migration file is migrated first because every one of my migration files contains a foreign key constraint.

Comment: It can be that, put postmen migration first and then trucks.

Comment: but I have foreign key constraints on all my migration. will that still work? I think it can only work when the first migration file has no foreign key constraints

Comment: I think you will need to change the order for your migrations. The INDEPENDENT tables must come first, and the referenced table must be on top of referencing table.

Comment: Right. But the problem is, I have no independent table. All my tables contain references. Because I don't know how else I can connect and update the values from each tables to one another without adding foreign key constraints on all of them

Comment: Can you show me he error that was thrown when you added my changes?

Comment: When I leave truck migration as it is, it shows no error but `postman_name` does not get updated. the value displayed as empty. When I tried to define foreign key constraints on truck migration, it throws the same error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table proj_db.trucks (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: What happen when you do this `$table->string('postman_name')->unique();` on postmen migration?

Comment: defining that in postmen migration and leaving truck migration alone does not throws error but`postman_name` does not get updated. the value displayed as empty.

Comment: And when you do this `return $this->hasOne(postman::class, 'postman_name','postman_name');` on Truck Model?

Comment: yeah same, when i do all ur suggestions without doing anything on truck migration, it does not give me error, but `postman_name` does not get updated. nothing to display

Comment: Your relashionship isn't well formed because the postmen foreign key is in trucks table, thus, `public function Truck(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Truck::class);
    }` is not right, you need `HasOne` or `HasMany` in Postman Model.

Comment: I see. the relationship between truck and postman is one to one. and truck is the main table. can I define HasOne on both truck and postman models? Like inside truck, it's hasOne postman. Inside postman, it's hasOne truck ?

Comment: So, in the Postman Model you specify `HasOne` and in trucks `belongsTo`.

Comment: Can you you me the code you use to return the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227405/discussion-between-mufida-zuhra-and-azafo-cossa).